# How to use more than one JPanel with Grouplayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, nullpointerexception, grouplayout

Im trying to add multiple `JPanel`s to my Frame and have them each use a `GroupLayout` but for some reason I either get `NullPointerException` or `Exception` in Thread main. What might I be doing wrong and how might I go about fixing it?

Would I then do `glayout2 = new GroupLayout(temp2Panel); temp2Panel.setLayout(glayout2); glayout2.setAutoCreateGaps(true); glayout2.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);` To make a second panel with grouplayout and will appear in the same Frame?

```
    public class test extends JFrame {
   /**
    * 
    */
   private JLabel testing;

   private JLabel lblcode;
   private JLabel lblemployeedetails;
   private JLabel lblname;
   private JLabel lbladdress;
   private JLabel lblcity;
   private JLabel lblemail;
   private JLabel lbltelnumber;
   private JLabel lblcellnumber;

   private JLabel lblprnumber;
   private JLabel lblppe;
   private JLabel lblppedate;
   private JTextField txtprnumber;
   private JTextField txtppe;

   private JTextField txtcode;
   private JTextField txtname;
   private JTextField txtaddress;
   private JTextField txtaddress2;
   private JTextField txtcity;
   private JTextField txtemail;
   private JTextField txttelnumber;
   private JTextField txtcellnumber;

   private Container container1;
   private Container container2;

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 6666;

   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp1Panel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp2Panel = new JPanel();

   private GroupLayout glayout;

   public test() {
      // Frame Parameters
      setTitle("test");
      setSize(500,500);// Adjust size of the frame/window
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);// Adjust open location



      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      });
/*************************************************************
 *  Properties~Always initialize within the constructor FOOL
*************************************************************/     
      testing = new JLabel("testing");

      lblcode= new JLabel("Code:");
      lblemployeedetails= new JLabel("Employee Details:");
      lblname= new JLabel("Name:");
      lbladdress= new JLabel("Address:");
      lblcity= new JLabel("City:");
      lblemail= new JLabel("Email:");
      lbltelnumber= new JLabel("Tel:");
      lblcellnumber= new JLabel("Cell:");
      lblprnumber = new JLabel("PR#:");
      lblppe = new JLabel("PPE:");
      lblppedate = new JLabel("PPE Date:");

      txtprnumber= new JTextField();
      txtppe= new JTextField();
      txtcode= new JTextField();
      txtname= new JTextField();
      txtaddress= new JTextField();
      txtaddress2= new JTextField();
      txtcity= new JTextField();
      txtemail= new JTextField();
      txttelnumber= new JTextField();
      txtcellnumber= new JTextField();
      //Below adding the 2 other panels to the main outer panel
      temp1Panel = new JPanel();
         temp1Panel.add(container1);
      temp2Panel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel = new JPanel();
         mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
         mainPanel.add(temp1Panel);
         mainPanel.add(temp2Panel);

/*************************************************************
 *               GroupLayout for temp1Panel
*************************************************************/

      container1 = getContentPane();
      glayout = new GroupLayout(temp1Panel);
      temp1Panel.setLayout(glayout);
      glayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      glayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);


      glayout.setHorizontalGroup(
         glayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblprnumber)
               .addComponent(lblcode)
               .addComponent(lblname)
               .addComponent(lbladdress)
               .addComponent(lblcity)
               .addComponent(lblemail)
               .addComponent(lbltelnumber)
               .addComponent(lblcellnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(txtprnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcode)
               .addComponent(txtname)
               .addComponent(txtaddress)
               .addComponent(txtaddress2)
               .addComponent(txtcity)
               .addComponent(txtemail)
               .addComponent(txttelnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcellnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblppe))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(txtppe)
               .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblppedate))
      );

      glayout.setVerticalGroup(
         glayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblprnumber)
               .addComponent(txtprnumber)
               .addComponent(lblppe)
               .addComponent(txtppe)
               .addComponent(lblppedate))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcode)
               .addComponent(txtcode)
               .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblname)
               .addComponent(txtname))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lbladdress)
               .addComponent(txtaddress))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(txtaddress2))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcity)
               .addComponent(txtcity))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblemail)
               .addComponent(txtemail))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lbltelnumber)
               .addComponent(txttelnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcellnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcellnumber))


      );

      this.setVisible(true);

   }//test

/*************************************************************
 *    Main 
*************************************************************/

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          new test();

      }//main

}
```

Edit 3: This is what I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GroupLayout can only be used with one Container at a time
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.checkParent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.invalidateLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.invalidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
```

Edit 4:

```
public class test extends JFrame {
   private static final int COLS = 30;
   /**
    * 
    */
   private JLabel testing;

   private JLabel lblcode;
   private JLabel lblemployeedetails;
   private JLabel lblname;
   private JLabel lbladdress;
   private JLabel lblcity;
   private JLabel lblemail;
   private JLabel lbltelnumber;
   private JLabel lblcellnumber;

   private JLabel lblprnumber;
   private JLabel lblppe;
   private JLabel lblppedate;
   private JTextField txtprnumber;
   private JTextField txtppe;

   private JTextField txtcode;
   private JTextField txtname;
   private JTextField txtaddress;
   private JTextField txtaddress2;
   private JTextField txtcity;
   private JTextField txtemail;
   private JTextField txttelnumber;
   private JTextField txtcellnumber;

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 6666;

   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp1Panel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp2Panel = new JPanel();

   private GroupLayout glayout;
   private GroupLayout glayout2;

   public test() {
      // Frame Parameters
      setTitle("test");
      setSize(500,500);// Adjust size of the frame/window
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);// Adjust open location



      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      });
/*************************************************************
 *  Properties~Always initialize within the constructor FOOL
*************************************************************/
      testing = new JLabel("test");

      lblcode = new JLabel("Code:");
      lblemployeedetails = new JLabel("Employee Details:");
      lblname = new JLabel("Name:");
      lbladdress = new JLabel("Address:");
      lblcity = new JLabel("City:");
      lblemail = new JLabel("Email:");
      lbltelnumber = new JLabel("Tel:");
      lblcellnumber = new JLabel("Cell:");
      lblprnumber = new JLabel("PR#:");
      lblppe = new JLabel("PPE:");
      lblppedate = new JLabel("PPE Date:");

      txtprnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtppe = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcode = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtname = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtaddress = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtaddress2 = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcity = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtemail = new JTextField(COLS);
      txttelnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcellnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      //Below adding the 2 other panels to the main outer panel
      temp1Panel = new JPanel();
      temp2Panel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel = new JPanel();
         mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
         mainPanel.add(temp1Panel);
         mainPanel.add(temp2Panel);
/*************************************************************
 *               GroupLayout for temp1Panel
*************************************************************/

      getContentPane().add(temp1Panel);//mainPanel

      glayout = new GroupLayout(temp1Panel);
      temp1Panel.setLayout(glayout);
      glayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      glayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);   

      glayout.setHorizontalGroup(
         glayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblprnumber)
               .addComponent(lblcode)
               .addComponent(lblname)
               .addComponent(lbladdress)
               .addComponent(lblcity)
               .addComponent(lblemail)
               .addComponent(lbltelnumber)
               .addComponent(lblcellnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(txtprnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcode)
               .addComponent(txtname)
               .addComponent(txtaddress)
               .addComponent(txtaddress2)
               .addComponent(txtcity)
               .addComponent(txtemail)
               .addComponent(txttelnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcellnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblppe))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(txtppe)
               .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(lblppedate))
      );

      glayout.setVerticalGroup(
         glayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblprnumber)
               .addComponent(txtprnumber)
               .addComponent(lblppe)
               .addComponent(txtppe)
               .addComponent(lblppedate))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcode)
               .addComponent(txtcode)
               .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblname)
               .addComponent(txtname))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lbladdress)
               .addComponent(txtaddress))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(txtaddress2))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcity)
               .addComponent(txtcity))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblemail)
               .addComponent(txtemail))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lbltelnumber)
               .addComponent(txttelnumber))
            .addGroup(glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
               .addComponent(lblcellnumber)
               .addComponent(txtcellnumber))

      );

      getContentPane().add(temp2Panel);

      glayout2 = new GroupLayout(temp2Panel);
      temp1Panel.setLayout(glayout2);
      glayout2.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      glayout2.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);  

      glayout2.setHorizontalGroup(
            glayout2.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGroup(glayout2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                  .addComponent(testing))

      );

      glayout2.setVerticalGroup(
            glayout2.createSequentialGroup()
               .addGroup(glayout2.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                  .addComponent(testing))

      );






      this.setVisible(true);

   }//test

/*************************************************************
 *    Main 
*************************************************************/

   public static void main(String[] args) {
          new test();

      }//main

}
```

Comment: What lines throw the exception?

Comment: See edit 3 to answer. The exception stacktrace suggests that you're trying to add one GroupLayout to more than one container. Please add another edit to the bottom of this one, one that shows the code that produces the exception that you're showing above.

Answer (score 4):

The line that throws the NPE will tell you exactly what's wrong:

```
  temp1Panel.add(container1);
```

You're trying to use a component, container1, before it has been initialized.

Suggestions:

- Don't do this. Initialize variables first before using them.
- Don't brush off exceptions but instead read them critically and study the lines that throw them as doing so will save you a lot of time in the future.
- If you need help with exceptions in the future, please be sure to post the exception stacktrace, and indicate with an obvious comment `// **** NullPointerException here ****` in your posted code.
- Your code is a bit strange. You appear to be adding the contentPane to one of your components -- it should be the other way around. Your code as written if it compiles will show **no** components.
- And I agree with Sage, GroupLayout is hard to work with for hand coding, but having said that, it's not impossible, and I have used it before.

---

**Edit**

- You don't even need the container1 variable as you do nothing with it. In essence, it is messing you up and providing you with no value, so get rid of it.

Your code with some modifications:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 6666;
   private static final int COLS = 10;

   private JLabel lblcode;
   private JLabel lblemployeedetails;
   private JLabel lblname;
   private JLabel lbladdress;
   private JLabel lblcity;
   private JLabel lblemail;
   private JLabel lbltelnumber;
   private JLabel lblcellnumber;

   private JLabel lblprnumber;
   private JLabel lblppe;
   private JLabel lblppedate;
   private JTextField txtprnumber;
   private JTextField txtppe;

   private JTextField txtcode;
   private JTextField txtname;
   private JTextField txtaddress;
   private JTextField txtaddress2;
   private JTextField txtcity;
   private JTextField txtemail;
   private JTextField txttelnumber;
   private JTextField txtcellnumber;

   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp1Panel = new JPanel();
   private JPanel temp2Panel = new JPanel();

   private GroupLayout glayout;

   public Test() {
      // Frame Parameters
      setTitle("test");
      // !! setSize(500, 500);// Adjust size of the frame/window
      // !! setLocationRelativeTo(null);// Adjust open location

      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
         }
      });
      // !! testing = new JLabel("testing");

      lblcode = new JLabel("Code:");
      lblemployeedetails = new JLabel("Employee Details:");
      lblname = new JLabel("Name:");
      lbladdress = new JLabel("Address:");
      lblcity = new JLabel("City:");
      lblemail = new JLabel("Email:");
      lbltelnumber = new JLabel("Tel:");
      lblcellnumber = new JLabel("Cell:");
      lblprnumber = new JLabel("PR#:");
      lblppe = new JLabel("PPE:");
      lblppedate = new JLabel("PPE Date:");

      // !! add COLS column size field
      txtprnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtppe = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcode = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtname = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtaddress = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtaddress2 = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcity = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtemail = new JTextField(COLS);
      txttelnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      txtcellnumber = new JTextField(COLS);
      temp1Panel = new JPanel();

      // add before using:
      // !! container1 = getContentPane(); // !!
      // !! temp1Panel.add(container1);
      temp2Panel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      mainPanel.add(temp1Panel);
      mainPanel.add(temp2Panel);

      getContentPane().add(mainPanel); // !!

      glayout = new GroupLayout(temp1Panel);
      temp1Panel.setLayout(glayout);
      glayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      glayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

      glayout
            .setHorizontalGroup(glayout
                  .createSequentialGroup()
                  .addGroup(
                        glayout
                              .createParallelGroup(
                                    GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(lblprnumber).addComponent(lblcode)
                              .addComponent(lblname).addComponent(lbladdress)
                              .addComponent(lblcity).addComponent(lblemail)
                              .addComponent(lbltelnumber)
                              .addComponent(lblcellnumber))
                  .addGroup(
                        glayout
                              .createParallelGroup(
                                    GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(txtprnumber).addComponent(txtcode)
                              .addComponent(txtname).addComponent(txtaddress)
                              .addComponent(txtaddress2).addComponent(txtcity)
                              .addComponent(txtemail)
                              .addComponent(txttelnumber)
                              .addComponent(txtcellnumber))
                  .addGroup(
                        glayout.createParallelGroup(
                              GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(
                              lblppe))
                  .addGroup(
                        glayout
                              .createParallelGroup(
                                    GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                              .addComponent(txtppe)
                              .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
                  .addGroup(
                        glayout.createParallelGroup(
                              GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(
                              lblppedate)));

      glayout.setVerticalGroup(glayout
            .createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblprnumber).addComponent(txtprnumber)
                        .addComponent(lblppe).addComponent(txtppe)
                        .addComponent(lblppedate))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblcode).addComponent(txtcode)
                        .addComponent(lblemployeedetails))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblname).addComponent(txtname))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lbladdress).addComponent(txtaddress))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(txtaddress2))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblcity).addComponent(txtcity))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblemail).addComponent(txtemail))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lbltelnumber).addComponent(txttelnumber))
            .addGroup(
                  glayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblcellnumber)
                        .addComponent(txtcellnumber))

      );

      pack(); // !!
      setLocationRelativeTo(null); // !!
      this.setVisible(true);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test();

   }

}
```

---

**Edit 2**  Regarding your edit to your question,

> Would I then do glayout2 = new GroupLayout(temp2Panel); temp2Panel.setLayout(glayout2); glayout2.setAutoCreateGaps(true); glayout2.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true); To make a second panel with grouplayout and will appear in the same Frame?

Sure, that could work. What happens when you try it?

---

**Edit 3**
The exception stacktrace suggests that you're trying to add one GroupLayout to more than one container. But your posted code does not reflect this problem. Please add another edit to the bottom of your latest one, one with the code that produces the exception that you're showing above.

Comment: It is probably just for me but I would not like to prefer using `GroupLayout` while hand coding. It is much more verbose than any other layout manager.

Comment: Would I then do glayout2 = new GroupLayout(temp2Panel);
      temp2Panel.setLayout(glayout2);
      glayout2.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
      glayout2.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

To make a second panel with grouplayout and will appear in the same Frame?

Comment: @user2933563: sure that could work. What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

1 / first you have to do JLayeredPane in your JFrame: `JLayeredPane panel_Contenu = new JLayeredPane ();`
2 / then you can do CardLayout for JLayeredPane`panel_Contenu.setLayout (new CardLayout (0, 0));` 
3 / at the end you have to add the other JPanels in the JLayeredPane `panel_Contenu.add (enter here the JPanel of other class you want to added);`